# How to convert feature image as background image

Tags: post-thumbnails

I am trying to set background image out of feature image so I used the `background-size:cover`. Here is the code I have done but how can I add feature image into `<div class="bg-img" style="background:...">`. How can I achieve background image technique.

```
if ( $post->post_parent )
    $post_id = $post->post_parent;
else
    $post_id = $post->ID;

if ( $thumbnail = get_the_post_thumbnail( $post_id, 'post-thumbnail' ) ) {
    echo $thumbnail;
}
```

Comment: You can use **get_the_post_thumbnail_url()** for get image url and put into **<div class="bg-img" style="background:PHP VARIABLE HERE">**

Answer (score 0):

**please use this code**

```
<?php $backgroundImg = wp_get_attachment_image_src( 
   get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), 'full' );?>

 <div class="header-wrap" style="background: url('<?php echo $backgroundImg[0]; ?>') no-repeat;">

 <header class="entry-header">

 <h1 class="entry-title">
 <?php the_title(); ?>
 </h1>

 </header>
```

Comment: How can you make the image appear for the parent and automatically apply to children like the code I pasted?